# How to append text to a specific lines in a file using shell script?

Tags: linux, shell-script, sed

I have a text file (file.txt) having content something like:

```
foo1 3464 
foo2 3696 
foo3 4562
```

It contains the process and respective PID.

Using shell script, I want to append a string (running/not running) to that lines in this file, according to the PID.

For example, in the above file, for line containing PID 3696, I want to append a string "running" at the end, so that the file becomes:

```
foo1 3464 
foo2 3696 running
foo3 4562
```

How can i do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With `perl`, by actually checking if the process is running (**Linux only**):

```
perl -ape '$pid = $F[1]; if (-d "/proc/$pid") {s/$/ running/}'
```

With `sed`:

```
sed -i '/\<3696\>/ s/$/ running/' "$file"
```

With `perl`:

```
perl -i -pe 's/$/ running/ if /\b3696\b/' "$file"

perl -i -ape 's/$/ running/ if $F[1] eq "3696"' "$file"
```

With `ed`:

```
ed "$file" <<-EOF
/\<3696\>/ s/$/ running/
wq
EOF
```

(Here `\< \>` (sed) and `\b \b` (perl) mean word boundaries – both examples only match "3696", but not "136960" or such.)

Comment: If i want to append the text according to the line no then what will be the command?